# How to undef a library function to use our version of same function

Tags: c

How to undef a library function to use my version of same function. Notice that I need to include the header file for other functions of same file. So not including is it not an option. Is there any way to use it without changing the name?

Comment: and i also dont want to change the name of the function.

Comment: With which compiler and operating system? And what exact library function you want to redefine?

Comment: Try with `#define that_function my_function`.

Comment: This is one of the reasons on why C++ was invented.

Comment: Is it `malloc()`?  Just curious.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001991/override-a-c-function-defined-in-a-static-library

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override a function call in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c)

Comment: What are your expectations for the scope of this replacement?  If you were to replace `malloc()`, for example, should that affect the behaviour of `strdup()`, which might call `malloc()`?

Comment: There are several possiblities to hide a function exported by a lib mentioned in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6540059/694576 to a similar question.

Comment: You might play `LD_PRELOAD` tricks on Linux.

Answer (score 10):

You can do the following:

```
#define function_name function_name_orig
#include <library.h>
#undef function_name

int function_name() {
    /* ... */
}
```

This way the function will not be defined by the header, since it will be replaced by `function_name_orig`. Implementations of getters or setters in the header file may continue to work - even if they use `function_name`, since those calls will also be replaced.

Comment: There's a minor hazard that `<library.h>` will do its own preprocessor magic to `function_name`.  It might even define `function_name` to call some other function altogether.

Answer (score -3):

For gcc, #undef seems to cut it, so long as you're keeping the same prototype for the function. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#undef scanf

int scanf(const char * s, ...)
{
    printf(s);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    scanf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles without warnings with -Wall, but if you want scanf to have a prototype of (say) `void scanf(void)` it will give errors.

Comment: This will only work if the "original" `scanf()` were a macro.