# Statically linking multiple libraries into one executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

I am building an application in which two static libraries have to be linked to my application.Both the static libraries have _DllMain defined and my application is throwing multiple definition linking error.

Is there a way to statically link multiple libraries into one application eventhough the static libraries share certain functions in common?

Comment: Why on earth static libraries have DllMain defined on them? Are you sure they are static?

Comment: Yes.Infact,those static libraries also have DLL's with the same code base.

Comment: It means they are buggy. You can't have two symbols with the same name in the executable. Bad luck.

Comment: I don't think this is possible... but maybe it is? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001991/override-a-c-function-defined-in-a-static-library) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c)