# How to replace symbols in object files

Tags: c++, linux, linker, ld, object-files

I want to rewrite object files so that most of the functions' addresses are altered to a no-op function. How can I do this?

More context: In C++ I want to auto-mock all functions by default. To go from having `a()` call `a() {}` and `b()` call `b() {}` to having `a()` really call `replacement() {}` and to have `b()` also call (the same) `replacement() {}`.

Things I've considered so far:

- `objcopy --redefine-syms=filename` - this changes the name of a symbol, not the address of it.
- Using the linker's `--wrap` argument - this requires compiling a distinct symbol `__wrap_NameOfWrappedThing` for each thing I want to wrap, and in general doesn't look like it'd scale nicely.

Comment: If using GCC or clang - have you tried [`__attribute__((weak))`](http://www.valvers.com/programming/c/gcc-weak-function-attributes/)?

Comment: @AConcagua - That requires a code change. My goal is to require no code changes, as I'd like to do this for all symbols.

Comment: Your --wrap approach might not replace all calls [either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961774/gnu-gcc-ld-wrapping-a-call-to-symbol-with-caller-and-callee-defined-in-the-sam) - they do not seem to have found a solution there yet.

Comment: Found a solution that's in the right ballpark: `objcopy --localize-symbols` can turn calls to "auto-mocked" functions into linker errors.

Comment: One thing I did not account for when considering an approach that alters object files is that inline functions can't be mocked in this way. This approach is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Hm - even if you decided to change code - as far as I know, weak attribute cannot be applied to inline functions either... Get more and more the impression that modifying the code itself is the easier solution, e. g. like this: `#if defined USE_MOCK && !defined UNMOCK_A`. You could then control the behaviour via compiler flags (-D)...