# C++ Ensuring We Call a Mocked System Call for Unit Testing

Tags: linux, unit-testing, mocking, g++, system-calls

When trying to wrap a system call in C++, such as lseek, the compiled code would call the actual system call instead of my mock.

Here's an example:

```
/* Mock the file operation lseek. */
off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence)
{
    printf("%s \n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

How to get the compiler to call my mocked system call rather than the one in unistd.h?

I tried using the -Wl,--wrap=lseek flag, but this failed as the linker could not find the __wrap_lseek symbol.

[GNU gcc/ld - wrapping a call to symbol with caller and callee defined in the same object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961774/gnu-gcc-ld-wrapping-a-call-to-symbol-with-caller-and-callee-defined-in-the-sam)

Answer (score 0):

I compiled with the g++ -c option then used the nm utility to look at the names of the symbols generated.

It turns out that the mocked system call names were being mangled by the C++ compiler. Thus, the linker would use the normal system call.

The solution was to wrap the mocked system calls with extern "C".

Here's a discussion on this keyword:

[How to correctly use the extern keyword in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)