# Cmocka unit testing with C: mocking nested function calls

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmocka

So, toy program that duplicates the issues I am having using cmocka for developing unit tests for existing code. The issue is a nested function call does not mock, which makes the unit test dependent on the nested function call performing properly. Please note, that "mockable_static" define was used as the original code has static functions that exist as "internal function calls", but for purposes of unit tests, these are open to external calls. ([See stackoverflow post where this idea came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898454/mock-wrap-static-functions-called-by-a-non-static-function-under-test))

Without further ado, here is the code:

func.h:

```
#ifndef FUNC_H_
#define FUNC_H_

#ifdef UNIT_TESTING
#define mockable_static
mockable_static char* bar();
#endif

char* foo();

#endif // FUNC_H_
```

func.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef UNIT_TESTING
#define mockable_static static
#else
#define mockable_static
#endif

mockable_static char* bar (){
    printf("This is bar!\n");
    char *str = "This is the result of bar!";
    return str;
}

char* foo(){
    printf("This is foo, and it should return the results of bar()\n");
    char * res;
    res = bar();
    return res;
}
```

test.c:

```
#include <setjmp.h> /* needs to be before cmocka.h */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmocka.h>

#include "func.h"

static void test_bar(void **state);
static void test_wrap_bar(void **state);
static void test_foo(void **state);

char* __real_bar();

char* __wrap_bar(){
    printf("This is a wrap and doesn't return bar!\n");
    return (char*)mock();
}

int main(void){
    //bar test
    const struct CMUnitTest bar_tests[] = {
        cmocka_unit_test(test_bar),
        cmocka_unit_test(test_wrap_bar)
    };
    const struct CMUnitTest foo_tests[] = {
        cmocka_unit_test(test_foo)
    };
    //foo test w/ mocking bar

    int status;
    status = cmocka_run_group_tests(bar_tests,NULL,NULL);
    status = cmocka_run_group_tests(foo_tests,NULL,NULL);

    printf("Status = %d\n",status);
    return status;
}

static void test_bar(void **state){
    char expected_res[] = "This is the result of bar!";
    char * actual_res;

    actual_res = __real_bar();
    assert_string_equal(actual_res,expected_res);
}

static void test_wrap_bar(void **state){
    char * this =  "I don't want bar!";
    will_return(__wrap_bar,this);

    char * res = bar();
    assert_string_equal(res,this);
}

static void test_foo(void **state){
    char * this =  "I don't want bar!";
    will_return(__wrap_bar,this);

    char * res = foo();
    assert_string_equal(res,this);
}
```

gcc compile line:

```
gcc ./test.c ./func.c -DUNIT_TESTING -g -Wl,--wrap=bar -o test -lcmocka-static
```

results on test execution:

```
[==========] Running 2 test(s).
[ RUN      ] test_bar
This is bar!
[       OK ] test_bar
[ RUN      ] test_wrap_bar
This is a wrap and doesn't return bar!
[       OK ] test_wrap_bar
[==========] 2 test(s) run.
[  PASSED  ] 2 test(s).
[==========] Running 1 test(s).
[ RUN      ] test_foo
This is foo, and it should return the results of bar()
This is bar!
[  ERROR   ] --- "This is the result of bar!" != "I don't want bar!"
[   LINE   ] --- ./test.c:59: error: Failure!
[  FAILED  ] test_foo
[==========] 1 test(s) run.
[  PASSED  ] 0 test(s).
[  FAILED  ] 1 test(s), listed below:
[  FAILED  ] test_foo

 1 FAILED TEST(S)
Status = 1
```

As you can see, bar() does not get wrapped in foo(), but in the wrap test, bar gets wrapped exactly as foo() calls bar. Bar is tested using __real_bar() which is a part of the cmocka test library (while __real_bar() has a prototype, the function is never defined and returns expected results as per cmocka documentation. Anyone have any experience using unit tests on nested function calls? I haven't found any results of mocking nested function calls with cmocka, but my google-foo might be lacking. If the assert is removed at the end of test_foo(), the test fails due to unused values in the will_return queue.

```
[==========] Running 2 test(s).
[ RUN      ] test_bar
This is bar!
[       OK ] test_bar
[ RUN      ] test_wrap_bar
This is a wrap and doesn't return bar!
[       OK ] test_wrap_bar
[==========] 2 test(s) run.
[  PASSED  ] 2 test(s).
[==========] Running 1 test(s).
[ RUN      ] test_foo
This is foo, and it should return the results of bar()
This is bar!
[  ERROR   ] --- %s() has remaining non-returned values.
./test.c:56: note: remaining item was declared here

[  FAILED  ] test_foo
[==========] 1 test(s) run.
[  PASSED  ] 0 test(s).
[  FAILED  ] 1 test(s), listed below:
[  FAILED  ] test_foo

 1 FAILED TEST(S)
Status = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so there are a few different avenues to solve this problem. I am posting the solution so someone else can see this.

Solution #1: separate nested function calls into separate .c files. IE- func.c contains foo() and (newfile)bar.c contains bar(). This allows the GCC --wrap=bar to work within func.c as it needs to link against another file.

Solution #2: build separate tests for testing bar and foo. Use the following line in func.c to make bar "weak"

```
__attribute__((weak))
mockable_static char* bar ().............(code follows)
```

In the file which is testing foo, with a mocked bar, we redefine bar() to act as the original char* __wrap_bar() function is defined. With the __attribute__((weak)), this redefined bar overrides the original bar, and we can proceed to force it to give results in the test file as we want.

The resulting test_foo.c file would look like this:

```
#include <setjmp.h> /* needs to be before cmocka.h */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmocka.h>

#include "func.h"
#include "bar.h"

static void test_bar(void **state);
static void test_wrap_bar(void **state);
static void test_foo(void **state);


char* bar(){
    printf("This is a wrap and doesn't return bar!\n");
    return (char*)mock();
}

int main(void){
    //bar test
    const struct CMUnitTest bar_tests[] = {
        cmocka_unit_test(test_wrap_bar)
    };
    const struct CMUnitTest foo_tests[] = {
        cmocka_unit_test(test_foo)
    };
    //foo test w/ mocking bar

    int status;
    status = cmocka_run_group_tests(bar_tests,NULL,NULL);
    status += cmocka_run_group_tests(foo_tests,NULL,NULL);

    printf("Status = %d\n",status);
    return status;
}

static void test_wrap_bar(void **state){
    char * this =  "I don't want bar!";
    will_return(bar,this);

    char * res = bar();
    assert_string_equal(res,this);
}

static void test_foo(void **state){
    char * this =  "I don't want bar!";
    will_return(bar,this);

    char * res = foo();
    assert_string_equal(res,this);
}
```

with the func.c file being:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef UNIT_TEST
#define mockable_static static
#else
#define mockable_static __attribute__((weak))
#endif


mockable_static char* bar (){
    printf("This is bar!\n");
    char *str = "This is the result of bar!";
    //char *str = "This is the resfjkl;dsaj of bar!";
    return str;
}

char* foo(){
    printf("This is foo, and it should return the results of bar()\n");
    char * res;
    res = bar();
    return res;
}
```

There would be a separate file, test_bar.c which would not redefine bar, and could test bar() within func.c.

Yay first solution is a solution to my own problem! Posting for others to see/comment/yell at me :)

Co-workers, thanks for helping with this!