# Wrapping function calls from static library error

Tags: c, function, linker, overriding

I have a static library which contains object files, I want to wrap a function which is called in one object file and is defined in another object file, I am trying to use the method suggested in [Override a function call in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c) using the `gcc --wrap` option.

Suppose I want to override a function `getnamei()`, I created a wrap.C file and defined `__wrap__getnamei()`, then compiled it to get an object file, then using the `--wrap` option I am able to override the function, but when I try to call the real function with `__real__getnamei()` in wrap.C, I get "error: '__real__getnamei() was not declared in this scope' ".

I am running on Windows 7, using MinGW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, in wrap.C we need to add a declaration of the function with `extern "C" __real__getnamei()`, then everything works fine!!