# Is there a way to capture any specific function call from a specific module that I may/may not have control over?

Tags: c, function, overriding, shared-libraries, system-calls

Say I have a DLL which includes `stdlib.h` and allocates some memory using `malloc` and later frees it using `free`. Is it possible for my main application to define a `malloc` function and a `free` function such that the DLL's `malloc` and `free` calls result in my main application's `malloc` and `free` functions being called?

If these functions I want to capture were not system calls and if I had control over my modules, I would have gone with the [approaches in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c).

I am trying to develop an application which links with certain modules. I do not want my main application itself to be affected by undefined behaviours in any module. Assuming it is possible for me to identify functions that need to be captured (like memory allocations/frees), is it possible to do such a thing portably?

I am currently working in Windows running Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Not in a platform-independent way, I think. Which compiler/linker and OS are you targeting?

Comment: @larsmans, Sorry. Forgot that bit. Edited the question.