# Using File Descriptors with readlink()

Tags: c, filenames, file-descriptor

I have a situation where I need to get a file name so that I can call the readlink() function. All I have is an integer that was originally stored as a file descriptor via an open() command. Problem is, I don't have access to the function where the open() command executed (if I did, then I wouldn't be posting this). The return value from open() was stored in a struct that I *do* have access to.

```
char buf[PATH_MAX];

char tempFD[2]; //file descriptor number of the temporary file created
tempFD[0] = fi->fh + '0';
tempFD[1] = '\0';

char parentFD[2]; //file descriptor number of the original file
parentFD[0] = (fi->fh - 1) + '0';
parentFD[1] = '\0';

if (readlink(tempFD, buf, sizeof(buf)) < 0) {
    log_msg("\treadlink() error\n");
    perror("readlink() error");
} else 
    log_msg("readlink() returned '%s' for '%s'\n", buf, tempFD);
```

This is part of the FUSE file system. The struct is called fi, and the file descriptor is stored in fh, which is of type uint64_t. Because of the way this program executes, I know that the two linked files have file descriptor numbers that are always 1 apart. At least that's my working assumption, which I am trying to verify with this code.

This compiles, but when I run it, my log file shows a readlink error every time. My file descriptors have the correct integer values stored in them, but it's not working.

Does anyone know how I can get the file name from these integer values? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it's acceptable that your code becomes non portable and is tied to being run on a somewhat modern version of Linux, then you can use `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>`. However, I would recommend against adding '0' to the fd as a means to get the string representing the number, because it uses the assumption that fd < 10.

However it would be best if you were able to just pick up the filename instead of relying on `/proc`. At the very least, you can replace calls to the library's function with a wrapper function using a linker flag. Example of usage is `gcc program.c -Wl,-wrap,theFunctionToBeOverriden -o program`, all calls to the library function will be linked against __wrap_theFunctionToBeOverriden; the original function is accessible under the name __real_theFunctionToBeOverriden. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/617606/111160 for details.

But, back to the answer not involving linkage rerouting: you can do it something like

```
 char fd_path[100];
 snprintf("/proc/%d/fd/%d", sizeof(fd_path), getpid(), fi->fh);
```

You should now use this `/proc/...` path (it is a softlink) rather than using the path it links to.

You can call `readlink` to find the actual path in the filesystem. However, doing so introduces a security vulnerability and I suggest against using the path `readlink` returns.

When the file the descriptor points at is deleted,unlinked, then you can still access it through the `/proc/...` path. However, when you `readlink` on it, you get the original pathname (appended with a ' (deleted)' text).

If your file was `/tmp/a.txt` and it gets deleted, `readlink` on the `/proc/...` path returns `/tmp/a.txt (deleted)`. If this path exists, you will be able to access it!, while you wanted to access a different file (`/tmp/a.txt`). An attacker may be able to provide hostile contents in the `/tmp/a.txt (deleted)` file.

On the other hand, if you just access the file through the `/proc/...` path, you will access the correct (unlinked but still alive) file, even if the path claims to be a link to something else.

Comment: Instead of `/proc/<pid>/fd`, you can use `/proc/self/fd`