# Using LD_PRELOAD to overload call to a C function of a shared library

Tags: c, gcc, ld, dynamic-linking

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/618059/880584) to override a call to a C function of a C library.

I think I did everything correctly, but it doesn't work:

I want to override the "DibOpen"-function. This is my code of the library which I pass to LD_PRELOAD environment-variable when running my application:

```
DIBSTATUS DibOpen(void **ctx, enum Board b)
{
    printf("look at me, I wrapped\n");

    static DIBSTATUS (*func)(void **, enum Board) = NULL;
    if(!func)
        func = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "DibOpen");
    printf("Overridden!\n");
    return func(pContextAddr, BoardType, BoardHdl);
}
```

The output of `nm lib.so | grep DibOpen` shows

```
000000000001d711 T DibOpen
```

When I run my program like this

```
LD_PRELOAD=libPreload.so ./program
```

I link my `program` with -ldl but `ldd program` does not show a link to libdl.so

It stops with

```
 symbol lookup error: libPreload.so: undefined symbol: dlsym
```

. What can I do to debug this further? Where is my mistake?

Comment: You need to link *`libPreload.so`*, not `program`, with `-ldl`.  If you're already doing that, please post your Makefile.

Comment: I wasn't even aware that you can link libraries between each others. It works now. Make your comment an answer, please. I use cmake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a shared library (whether or not it will be used in `LD_PRELOAD`), you need to name all of the libraries that *it* needs to resolve its dependencies.  (Under some circumstances, a `dlopen`ed shared object can rely on the executable to provide symbols for it, but it is best practice not to rely on this.)  In this case, you need to link `libPreload.so` against `libdl`.  In Makefile-ese:

```
libPreload.so: x.o y.o z.o
        $(CC) -shared -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--as-needed -o $@ $^ -ldl
```

The option `-Wl,-z,defs` tells the linker that it should issue an error if a shared library has unresolved undefined symbols, so future problems of this type will be caught earlier.  The option `-Wl,--as-needed` tells the linker not to record a dependency on libraries that don't actually satisfy any undefined symbols.  Both of these *should* be on by default, but for historical reasons, they aren't.