# Two declarations of the same function in c

Tags: c

I had this question in a test, and I still don't understand the answer I was given:

Let's say I wrote the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float cos(float x){
    return 1-x*x/4;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%0f",cos(0.05f)+sin(0.05f));
}
```

Let's assume `cos` and `sin` are declared and defined in the math library (receiving and returning `double`), and I'm trying to link my code with the math library.

Another assumption is that `cos` is defined in `math.c`.

The question was:

> "Will the code compile/link successfully? if so, which *cos* function
>   will be called?"

The answer was:

> "Yes, the code will compile and my *cos* will be called".

How could this behavior be explained? Aren't these multiple definitions of the same function?

Comment: How did you arrive at your answer `""Yes, the code will compile and my cos will be called""`?

Comment: @Brandin that was the teacher's solution.

Comment: Compiling with GCC-4.8.1 I get an error: "conflicting types for 'cos'"

Comment: @Paz I think it is implementation depenedent. It means your teacher's solution is not correct. If you actually want to redefine cos you should name it something else like `my_cos`. Then for convenience you could `#define cos(X) my_cos((X))` in the source files where you want to use your custom version

Comment: @Brandin: it is not implementation dependent, cos is a standard function and overloading is not allowed in C.

Comment: Your teacher may have made a mistake and intended to use `double cos(double x)`. In this case, many C implementations will accept the program, and it will link and run because the linker takes **every** module from the object modules it is supplied but only takes the **needed** modules from the libraries it is supplied. Thus, because `cos` is already defined in the program, the linker will not take it from the math library. However, although this works in many C implementations, it violates the rules of standard C, which reserves the library identifiers; normal programs may not define them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'd make your comment an answer. I think you've hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Ouch, again one of these course questions about C where obviously the teacher doesn't fully understand C himself.

Comment: @paz would you please check my answer? As I found a topic here similar to the case you want exactly, you can override the math.h library...

Comment: @AhmedHamdy thanks for the attempt, but I asked my teacher and he explained his intention: using math as a statically linked library, and in that case our "local" version of 'cos' will be chosen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your teacher may have made a mistake and intended to use `double cos(double x)`. In this case, many C implementations will accept the program, and it will link and run because the linker takes **every** module from the object modules it is supplied but only takes the **needed** modules from the libraries it is supplied. Thus, because `cos` is already defined in the program, the linker will not take it from the math library. However, although this works in many C implementations, it violates the rules of standard C, which reserves the library identifiers; normal programs may not define them.

Another possibility is that your teacher did not intend to include `math.h`. This would make the declaration of `cos` not be an error, since it would not be conflicting with another declaration, but it would mean that `sin` should also be declared by the program, since it is used.

Comment: The question states that in our (hypothetical) case cos is defined in math.c, and not math.h. Does that change things much?

Comment: @Paz: It depends on how the program is linked. If math.c is compiled to math.o and linked, I expect the linker to complain about multiple definitions of `cos`. If math.o is put into a library, such as libm.a, and then linked, I would expect the linker to take just the first definition and not complain. In a situation like this, I would consider that replacing the teacher might be the best option.

Comment: Your latter suggestion must be what they meant.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work at all.

You will see an error like this one:

```
conflicting types for 'cos'
```

I got it with codeblocks with gcc compiler ...

There is another solution you can use, please check this post:  [Override a function call in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c)

Comment: If `cos` is a macro definition, and you called `#undef cos` before redefining `cos` it would be okay.  I'm pretty sure `cos` isn't a macro though.

Comment: @FiddlingBits that isn't mentioned in the question, so I'm assuming that isn't the case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your error output does not come from codeblocks but the compiler called by codeblocks.

Answer (score 2):

It will not compile.

I added a `return 0;` at the end of `main()` to remove a second problem with `-Wall -Werror`. If you do this you will see:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror costest1.c -o costest -lm
costest1.c:5:1: error: conflicting types for ‘cos’
```

This fails at the compile stage because `math.h` also defines a function called `cos`. Note the prototype for `cos` is:

```
double cos(double x);
```

not

```
float cos(float x);
```

If you did not include `math.h`, you would be able to compile, but would get:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror costest1.c -o costest -lm
costest1.c:5:1: error: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cos’ [-Werror]
costest1.c: In function ‘main’:
costest1.c:13:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘sin’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
costest1.c:13:32: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘sin’ [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

This is because `cos` is not a normal function, but handled as a `builtin`. As you can see it's defined in terms of `sin`. If `cos` were a normal function, you would see a duplicate symbol error of some sort.

In C you cannot have two functions with the same name even if they have different arguments. In C++ you can, in that identically named methods may differ by the calling parameters (but not just by the return type).

Comment: Using `-Werror` is not a valid test of whether a program conforms to standard C, as it alters the behavior of the compiler to reject some conforming programs.

Comment: Fair enough. Without `-Werror` it compiles, but I believe this is because `cos` is defined in `math.h` in terms of `sin`, so there is no actual function `cos` in the library.

Comment: In particular not having a `return` statement in `main` is completely valid. `main` is special in that regard.

Comment: I thought you were meant to declare `main()` as `void` if you did not want to return a value.

Comment: @abligh The `main()` function must always be defined to have a return value of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

I assume the question was about C++ and not C since compiling your code as a C program will generate conflicting types error: https://eval.in/93380.

This behaviour is caused by the [Function Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). The `cos()` function has the assembly name `_cos@double` and redeclaring the `cos()` function to be accepting a `float` argument will have the assembly name`_cos@float`and it will not conflict with the `cos()` defined in the math library. And calling `cos()` with a `float` argument will be translated to a call to the assembly function `_cos@float` which is your own `cos()`.

*Note that [Function Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) is allowed only in C++ and not C.*

In C you can only do it without changing the arguments and the return types of the function (https://eval.in/93381) otherwise the previous error will be generated.

As the assumption clarifies (cos is defined in math.c), the `cos()` function in the case is other than the one defined in the `math.h` in which case the the answer would be true if it was defined to be accepting an argument of type `float` and returning a value of type `float`. In this case the program will compile without any issues.

Comment: unfortunately it is indeed C and not C++.

Comment: @Paz This can't be true in C as you're redefining `cos` with different arguments types. This will always generate conflicting types error https://eval.in/93368

Comment: it was explicitly mentioned in the test that the math.h\math.c version of cos() is defined with 'double'. So this double definition will inevitably cause an error?

Comment: @Paz If this is the case your teacher may have made a mistake.

Comment: @Paz: yes, it's a constraint violation (see my answer below).  If your teacher is successfully compiling that code and running it as described, then he or she is either using a C++ compiler or a seriously non-conforming C compiler.

Comment: @JohnBode Which is clearly described and answers has votes up to +5 and non of them was accepted!

Answer (score 2):

[Online C2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.7 Declarations**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> ...
> 4 All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or function shall specify
> compatible types

The code you posted violates the above constraint; `math.h` declares `cos` as

```
double cos(double x);
```

This behavior cannot be explained *as C*; it can be explained as C++, which allows for name overloading.

Make sure you're really talking about C and not C++, otherwise you are going to wind up being *very* confused.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not compile.

The header file `math.h` declares `double cos(double)`. Attempting to overload is not allowed in C.

```
error C2371: 'cos' : redefinition; different basic types
```

Comment: At least in your environment.  See @Eric's answer above.

Comment: In any environment. This MUST raise a compilation error. Function signatures must be declared uniquely in C. Eric does not contradict this.