# Hook C application function call

Tags: c++, c, linux, hook

I am working on Linux.

I would like to hook C program function which is declared as static or global,

For example: I have a function name my_func and I would like to replace it in runtime
to hook_my_func, when I am looking at the ELF file (without debugging symbols) I don't see
the function symbol of my_func.

Is there a way to hook the function in run time ?

(I am capable to hook this function, only when it reside as a shared library but I want to hook it when it is private function of the C application)

Comment: If you don't have debugging symbols then how can you locate the function you're interested in?  What do you see if you run `strings my_prog | grep my_func`?

Comment: Nothing, plus also from read-elf I don't see it, since there is no debugging symbols.

Comment: And the adress will not be the same each time as i suppose and also will not work. ( I still wonder, how powerful tools hook windows and linux , if let me say, kernel is compiled without debugging symbols).

Comment: Are you able to call this function? Do you have source code?

Comment: Yes, I written also the C program, for the purpose of testing, but still without debug symbols I can't locate the function address.

Comment: You need to add `-rdynamic` when build your app with gcc so that global functions can be seen by `readelf`.

Comment: There has been a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c. You insist on _runtime_ but peharps this question can be of use for you. Personally I like `--wrap symbol` option (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ld.htm)