# Wrapping functions with macros (without renaming) C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Im interested to add in some extra logic around existing function calls, by wrapping them **without** renaming them. *(just for a test)*.

The existing solutions I found rely on wrapping a function in a macro of a different name, which can mean changing a lot of code.

Any suggestions?

---

Note, I'm aware of `LD_PRELOAD`, but am interested to use macro's to be able to inspect the arguments passed to the function (using `_Generic` for example).

Comment: As an alternative to macro magic, you find might answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c) interesting. Especially [the one about LD_PRELOAD](http://stackoverflow.com/a/618059/1717300) and [the one about `--wrap`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/617606/1717300).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's normally no need to rename macro-wrapped functions because inside the expansion of a macro, the macro's name is not expanded.

Here's an example straight from the C11 standard:

```
#define cbrt(X) _Generic((X),               \
                        long double: cbrtl, \
                        default: cbrt,      \
                        float: cbrtf        \
                        )(X)
```

Of course, you'll run into problems if you've `#include <tgmath.h>` because in that case you'll already have type-generic macros, such as the above, and you won't be able to redefine `sqrt` (unless you `#undef` it). And you must `#include <math.h>` before defining that macro.

Even so, you're treading on thin ice. The standard reserves the names of standard library functions, and insists that (§7.1.3/2):

> If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

The referenced section 7.1.4 does allow you to `#undef` a function-like macro which shadows a standard-library function, but it is not clear to me that you are allowed to subsequently redefine it. YMMV.

---

If you wanted to use `_Generic` to call a wrapper function, you can still make that work without renaming the original function. For example:

```
#include <nanny.h>

/* In this file, you can't call nanny(char), and if you call it
 * with an unsigned argument, we'll insert an additional check
 */

#define nanny(X) _Generic((X), int: nanny, unsigned:nanny_wrapper)(X)

int nanny_wrapper(unsigned x) {
  assert(x < INT_MAX);
  /* The redundant parentheses prevent macro expansion */
  return (nanny)(x);
}
```

Comment: Defining or undefining a standard macro causes undefined behavior. I believe this applies even if you don't include a header with its definition, but even if you include any standard header. (I might just be applying a rule from C++, though.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: C is more liberal. "Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for use as specified *if any of its associated headers is included* unless explicitly stated otherwise"

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Also, it seems (&sect;7.1.4) to be valid to `#undef` a function-like macro defined by a standard library header if that function-like macro shadows the definition of a standard library function. The standard library is required to make standard functions available as functions, even if it chooses to use function-like macros to shadow them for efficiency (or whatever).

Comment: @rici - Ok. the point of confusion here, is that the defines for the functions `cbrt`, need to be included first (in retrospect its obvious - but including the header after the define will obviously break).

Comment: @ideasman42: Added that to the answer, with a quote from the standard.

Answer (score 1):

For example, lets say I want to check the types on a function call.

A simple case, I want to check that `sqrt` only takes (`int` or `double`), not `float`.

Here is a method that works OK.

```
/* add this to a header or at the top of the source-code */
#include <math.h>
static typeof(&sqrt) sqrt_wrap = sqrt;
#define sqrt(f) (_Generic((f), int: sqrt_wrap, double: sqrt_wrap))(f)
```

This works but has some drawbacks.

- Must include `<math.h>`, or at least define `sqrt` since we dont know if the static function is called or not.
- Defines a function all over which may be unused. though `__attribute__((__unused__))` works in works in GCC/Clang.
- All output must have access to the function symbol, even if it ends up not using `sqrt`.

Edit!

---

This does in fact work, the header just needs to be included first *(obviously - in retrospect)*

```
#include <math.h>
#define sqrt(f) _Generic((f), int: sqrt(f), double: sqrt(f))
```

Heres a trick to check `sqrt` isn't called with `float` and `sqrtf` isn't called with `double`

```
#include <math.h>
#define sqrt(X)  _Generic((X), float:  NULL, default: sqrt)(X)
#define sqrtf(X) _Generic((X), double: NULL, default: sqrtf)(X)
```

Comment: Did you not notice the `C` tag?

Comment: Wait, I just noticed that you are the OP. Okay, would you care to tag your question properly?

Comment: Did you try and see if the supposedly broken code works? Macros have always supported this; it's not just about `_Generic`.

Comment: @CareyGregory It's tagged properly; why not clarify your objection?

Comment: @Potatoswatter It's tagged `C`. C has no such thing as `typeof` nor the syntax used in the `#define`.

Comment: @CareyGregory `typeof` is an extension, albeit a common one, but it's an extension to C and not something else. The syntax used in the `#define` is a standard C feature since 2011.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I understand that now, but tagging it `C11` sure would have clarified things. Very few people are going to recognize C11 syntax as C.