# How to intercept a static library call in C language?

Tags: c, compilation, linker

Here's my question:
There is a static library (xxx.lib) and some C files who are calling function `foo()` in xxx.lib. I'm hoping to get a notification message every time `foo()` is called. But I'm not allowed to change any source code written by others.

I've spent several days searching on the Internet and found several similar Q&As but none of these suggestions could really solve my problem. I list some of them:

1. use `gcc -wrap`: [Override a function call in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c) 
   Thank god, I'm using Microsoft C compiler and linker, and I can't find an equivalent option as `-wrap`.
2. Microsoft Detours:
   Detours intercepts C calls in runtime and re-direct the call to a trampoline function. But Detours is only free for IA32 version, and it's not open source.
3. I'm thinking about injecting a jmp instruction at the start of function `foo()` to redirect it to my own function. However it's not feasible when `foo()`is empty, like

   ```
     void foo() --->  will be compiled into 0xC3 (ret)
     {                but it'll need at least 8 bytes to inject a jmp
     }
   ```
4. I found a technology named [Hotpatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173524.aspx) on MSDN. It says the linker will add serveral bytes of padding at the beginning of each function. That's great, because I can replace the padding bytes with jmp instruction to realize the interception in runtime! But when I use the /FUNCTIONPADMIN option with the linker, it gives me a warning:

   ```
   LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/FUNCTIONPADMIN'; ignored
   ```

   Anybody could tell me how could I make a "hotpatchable" image correctly? Is it a workable solution for my question ?

Do I still have any hope to realize it ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without a lot of fiddling. Object files aren't exactly designed to do that.

Comment: To be honest, I would go for option 3. But first, you will have to locate the function you would like to redirect, as there won't be any export like when you have a DLL. So yes, it can be done, but there's much work involved.

A link that might help: [Small tutorial](https://securitycafe.ro/2015/01/28/intercepting-functions-from-statically-linked-libraries/)

Comment: Yes, I saw this article. But it's not practical in a real project. I do hope for a method to intercept a function call in runtime. Wondering how Detours did it....

Comment: I have not much experience in windows. can you check this ? http://wwwold.cs.umd.edu/Library/TRs/CS-TR-4585/CS-TR-4585.pdf

Comment: thanks @ManthanTilva, this article gives same solutions as I listed above. but they're not fit for me.

Comment: What about something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617554/override-a-function-call-in-c
looks like thats the same thing you found :/

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source, you can instrument the code with GCC without changing the source by adding `-finstrument-functions` for the build of the files containing the functions you are interested in. You'll then have to write __cyg_profile_func_enter/exit functions to print your tracing. An example from [here](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static FILE *fp_trace;

void
__attribute__ ((constructor))
trace_begin (void)
{
 fp_trace = fopen("trace.out", "w");
}

void
__attribute__ ((destructor))
trace_end (void)
{
 if(fp_trace != NULL) {
 fclose(fp_trace);
 }
}

void
__cyg_profile_func_enter (void *func,  void *caller)
{
 if(fp_trace != NULL) {
 fprintf(fp_trace, "e %p %p %lu\n", func, caller, time(NULL) );
 }
}

void
__cyg_profile_func_exit (void *func, void *caller)
{
 if(fp_trace != NULL) {
 fprintf(fp_trace, "x %p %p %lu\n", func, caller, time(NULL));
 }
}
```

Another way to go if you have source to recompile the library as a shared library. From there it is possible to do runtime insertions of your own .so/.dll using any number of debugging systems. (ltrace on unix, something or other on windows [somebody on windows -- please edit]).

If you don't have source, then I would think your option 3 should still work. Folks writing viruses have been doing it for years. You may have to do some manual inspection (because x86 instructions aren't all the same length), but the trick is to pull out a full instruction and replace it with a jump to somewhere safe. Do what you have to do, get the registers back into the same state as if the instruction you removed had run, then jump to just after the jump instruction you inserted.

Comment: Many thanks for your help~ I just posted a solution by using options `\Gh` and `\GH`. These 2 options do similar things as GCC option `-finstrument-functions` does. :)

Answer (score 1):

The VC compiler provides 2 options [`/Gh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx) & [`/GH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc11y76y.aspx) for hooking functions.

The `/Gh` flag causes a call to the `_penter` function at the start of every method or function, and the `/GH` flag causes a call to the `_pexit` function at the end of every method or function.

So, if I write some code in `_penter` to find out the address of the caller function, then I'll be able to intercept any function selectively by comparing the function address.

I made a sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{

}

void bar()
{

}

void main() {
  bar();
  foo();
  printf ("I'm main()!");
}


void __declspec(naked) _cdecl _penter( void ) 
{
    __asm {
        push ebp;               // standard prolog
        mov ebp, esp;
        sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE
        pushad;                 // save registers
    }

    unsigned int addr;
    // _ReturnAddress always returns the address directly after the call, but that is not the start of the function!
    // subtract 5 bytes as instruction for call _penter
    // is 5 bytes long on 32-bit machines, e.g. E8 <00 00 00 00>
    addr = (unsigned int)_ReturnAddress() - 5;

    if (addr == foo) printf ("foo() is called.\n");
    if (addr == bar) printf ("bar() is called.\n");

    _asm {
        popad;              // restore regs
        mov esp, ebp;       // standard epilog
        pop ebp;
        ret;
    }
}
```

Build it with `cl.exe source.c /Gh` and run it:

`bar() is called.
foo() is called.
I'm main()!`

It's perfect!

More examples about how to use `_penter` and `_pexit` can be found here [A Simple Profiler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47532/A-Simple-Profiler-using-the-Visual-Studio-C-C-Comp) and [tracing with penter pexit](http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c/121916-poor-mans-tracing-penter-pexit.html) and [A Simple C++ Profiler on x64](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/800172/A-Simple-Cplusplus-Profiler-on-x).

I've solved my problem using this method, and I hope it can help you also.

:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any to do this without changing any code.
Easiest way I can think of is to do this is to write wrapper for your `void foo()` function and Find/Replace it with your wrapper.

```
void myFoo(){
     return foo();
}
```

Instead of calling `foo()` call `myFoo()`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Appreciate it. I know what I'm asking for is somewhat out of reach, but I'm still expecting a miracle to turn up. :)