# How to get a caller graph from a given symbol in a binary

Tags: c++, gcc, callstack, nm, radare2

This question is related to [a question I've asked earlier this day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832883/how-to-statically-identify-dynamic-heap-allocation): I wonder if it's possible to generate a caller graph from a given function (or symbol name e.g. taken from `nm`), *even if the function of interest is not part of "my" source code (e.g. located in a library, e.g. `malloc()`)*

For example to know where `malloc` is being used in my program named `foo` I would first lookup the symbol name:

```
nm foo | grep malloc
         U malloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

And then run a tool (which might need a specially compiled/linked version of my program or some compiler artifacts):

```
 find_usages foo-with-debug-symbols "malloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5"
```

Which would generate a (textual) caller graph I can then process further.

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517589/tools-to-get-a-pictorial-function-call-graph-of-code) I found [radare2](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/analysis/code_analysis.html) which seems to accomplish nearly everything you can imagine but somehow I didn't manage to generate a caller graph from a given symbol yet..

**Progress**

Using `radare2` I've managed to generate a `dot` caller graph from an executable, but something is still missing. I'm compiling the following C++ program which I'm quite sure has to use `malloc()` or `new`:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  auto s = std::string("hello");
  s += " welt";
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it with static libraries in order to be sure all calls I want to analyze can be found in the binary:

```
g++ foo.cpp -static
```

By running `nm a.out | grep -E "_Znwm|_Znam|_Znwj|_Znaj|_ZdlPv|_ZdaPv|malloc|free"` you can see a lot of symbols which are used for memory allocation.

Now I run `radare2` on the executable:

```
r2 -qAc 'agCd' a.out > callgraph.dot
```

With a little script (inspired by [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16277)) I'm looking for a call-path from any symbol containing "sym.operatornew" but there seems to be none!

Is there a way to make sure *all* information needed to generate a call graph from/to *any* function which get's called inside that binary?

Is there a better way to run radare2? It looks like the different call graph visualization types provide different information - e.g. the ascii art generator does provide names for symbols not provided by the dot generator while the dot generator provides much more details regarding calls.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you cannot extract an *exact* control flow graph from a binary, because of [indirect jumps and calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_branch) there. A machine code indirect call is jumping into the content of some register, and you cannot *reliably* estimate all the values that register could take (doing so could be proven equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)).

> Is there a way to make sure all information needed to generate a call graph from/to any function which get's called inside that binary?

**No**, and *that problem is equivalent to the halting problem*, so there would be never a sure way to get that call graph (in a complete and sound way).

The C++ compiler would (usually) generate indirect jumps for virtual function calls (they jump thru the [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)) and probably when using a shared library (read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper for more).

Look into the [BINSEC](http://binsec.gforge.inria.fr/tools) tool (developed by colleagues from CEA, LIST and by INRIA), at least to find references.

If you really want to find most (but not all) dynamic memory allocations in your C++ source code, you might use static source code analysis (like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) or [Frama-Clang](https://frama-c.com/frama-clang.html)) and other tools, but they are not a silver bullet.

Remember that allocating functions like `malloc` or `operator new` could be put in function pointer locations (and your C++ code might have some [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) deeply buried somewhere, then you are likely to have *indirect* calls to `malloc`)

Maybe you could spend months of effort in writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to look for calls to `malloc` *after optimizations* inside the GCC compiler (but notice that GCC plugins are tied to one particular version of GCC). I am not sure it is worth the effort. My old (obsolete, non maintained) [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project [was](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/tutousemelt.html) able to find calls to `malloc` with a size above some given constant. Perhaps in at least a year -end of 2019 or later- my successor project ([bismon](http://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/), funded by [CHARIOT](http://chariotproject.eu/) H2020 project) might be mature enough to help you.

Remember also that GCC is capable of quite fancy optimizations related to `malloc`. Try to compile the following C code

```
//file mallfree.c
#include <stdlib.h>
int weirdsum(int x, int y) {
  int*ar2 = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
  ar2[0] = x; ar2[1] = y;
  int r = ar2[0] + ar2[1];
  free (ar2);
  return r;
}
```

with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O3 mallfree.c`. You'll see that the generated `mallfree.s` assembler file contain no call to `malloc` or to `free`. Such an optimization is permitted by the [As-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule), and is practically useful to optimize most usages of C++ standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

So **what you want is *not simple***  even for apparently "simple" C++ code (and **is *impossible*** in the general case).

If you want to code a GCC plugin and have more than a full year to spend on that issue (or could pay at least 500k€ for that), please contact me. See also 
https://xkcd.com/1425/ (your question is a *virtually impossible* one).

BTW, of course, what you really care about is dynamic memory allocation in *optimized* code (you really want [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) and [dead code elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination), and GCC does that quite well with  `-O3` or `-O2`). When GCC is not optimizing at all (e.g. with `-O0` which is the implicit optimization) it would do a lot of "useless" dynamic memory allocation, specially with C++ code (using the C++ standard library). See also CppCon 2017: Matt Godbolt *“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”* [talk](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4).

Comment: I don't need a control flow graph but just a tree. My primary goal is to identify functions which *might* call a certain function. This is an easy task - there are many call graph generators out there - but I need to generate a call graph down to standard library functions. (e.g. `new`, `delete`, `malloc()`, `free()` etc.)

Comment: This is *not* an easy task. A function pointer location might *sometimes* contain the address of `malloc` -or of some `operator new` function inside a C++ class.

Comment: You're right of course - but leave aside function pointers for now. In the example snippet I provided I create and modify a `std::string` and for now I'm just looking for a tool, which would (implicitly) tell me that somewhere inside `main()` I might call `new` or `malloc()`

Comment: In your answer you provide scenarios in which it's hard/impossible to spot a certain function call due to optimization. But in my case the source code is completely available and for analyzing purposes I can compile it with all options needed for that (`-O0`, `-static`, `-fno-function-cse`, `-fomit-frame-pointer`, etc). So I could also use a static source code analyzer but I don't know any tool which would *also consider the standard libraries*.

Comment: Then code your own GCC plugin to do that (you'll need a year of work). Notice that quite often `operator new` could be inlined or specialized inside the standard C++ library. You'll find out that your problem is really hard (and much harder than what it looks at first). I am working in a lab which has several experts on that question.